# Error reading Kafka SSL client truststore file from Spark streaming

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark streaming application reading from Kafka. I am running it from EMR. Recently I implemented Kafka SSL. I am creating the Kafka client as shown below. I am getting a strange error running the application when it tries to read the truststore file. 
Error is:

```
- Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks (No such file or directory)
```

What is causing this issue?

```js
DataStreamReader df = session.readStream()
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",kafka_server)
    .option("subscribe", kafka_topic)
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
    .option("group.id", kafka_group)
    .option("kafka.security.protocol","SSL")
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location","/tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks")
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password","clientpass");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file must exist on the executor nodes of the cluster, not just on the machine you submit the code from

Otherwise, you must pass the --files option to spark-submit to pass them from your machine to the driver, then you could remove `/tmp/` part of your string path as well, since the file should be directly accessible

Also note: group.id isn't allowed in structured streaming ; in Spark docs you'll see it's `kafka.group.id`

Comment: Thanks cricket_007 it worked. However I kept the group id and didn't see any issue. Is there any harm in keeping it ?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. Spark generates a random one

Comment: @Anirban how did you put the files on every executor node?

Comment: @Iamnot `--files`, as mentioned