# Read Kafka store file location from S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, databricks, aws-databricks

We are getting below error so we started to get kafka key and certificate from S3 location (s3://my-bucket/tmp/k2/truststore.jks) on databricks notebook

```
DbxDlTransferError: Terminated with exception: Kafka store file location only supports external location or UC Volume path on Shared cluster. Use external location or UC Volume Path to provide it.: None
```

But while reading S3 location we are getting another error

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: s3:/my-bucket/tmp/k2/truststore.jks
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
at kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.load(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:368)
... 86 more
```

> We pass S3 location with "//" but when java reads it, there is only
> "/" slash.

I tried looking online but couldn't find any solution. If someone has any idea please share here. Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
truststore_location = "s3://my-bucket/tmp/k2/truststore.jks"
cluster_ca_certificate_location = "s3://my-bucket/tmp/k2/cluster-ca-certificate.pem"


kafka_server = "server_ip:9093"

kafka_topic = "kafka_topic"
kafka_group_id = "group_id"
scram_login_module = 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="" password=""'

input_df = (
  spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_server)
  .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", truststore_location)
  .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", truststore_pass)
  .option("kafka.ssl.ca.location", cluster_ca_certificate_location)
  .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
  .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-256")
  .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", "kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username='{}' password='{}';".format(consumer_username, consumer_password))
  .option("subscribe", kafka_topic)
  .option("kafka.group.id", kafka_group_id)
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
  .load()
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error reading Kafka SSL client truststore file from Spark streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59274128/error-reading-kafka-ssl-client-truststore-file-from-spark-streaming)

Comment: Thanks @FilippoTestini , this won't solve my problem. I m looking how can I reads trust files from s3 location.

Answer (score 0):

> there is only "/" slash.

From the stacktrace, you can see Spark uses Java `Files.newInputStream` and `UnixFileSystemProvider`. This can only read local files, not S3 buckets, therefore doesn't understand `s3://`.

You'll need to use S3 SDK to first download the file into a temp directory before writing any Spark code

For example rather than using a notebook, use a shell script

```
aws s3 cp s3://.../file.jks  /tmp/file.jks
spark-submit --files /tmp/file.jks ...
```

Alternatively, you need to set option `kafka.ssl.engine.factory.class` to a [JVM implementation](https://kafka.apache.org/27/javadoc//org/apache/kafka/common/security/auth/SslEngineFactory.html) that reads files from S3 rather than local disk.

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer , but as per databricks we should be able to read Kafka store file from external location. We cannot download locally for security reasons.

Comment: Please link to Databricks documentation where that's mentioned. I think you're confusing checkpoint location with other files... The stacktrace tells the full story, there's no way to change how / where the CA file & truststore is read since it's Kafka library doing the actual reading, not Spark

Comment: At least, Spark / Python can't change it. In the Kafka documentation, there's a setting `ssl.engine.factory.class`, and requires writing a Java plugin to override it

Comment: @ArvindPant how did you resolve the issue?

Comment: hi @OneCricketeer, Hassan, working with databricks team. Will post answer here once I have update from databricks team.

Comment: @ArvindPant As indicated, you'll have to override DefaultSslEngineFactory in the Kafka config using the setting mentioned above

Comment: @OneCricketeer, you mean this one?

"At least, Spark / Python can't change it. In the Kafka documentation, there's a setting ssl.engine.factory.class, and requires writing a Java plugin to override it"

Comment: @ArvindPant Yes, you'll need to write Java class that implements SslEngineFactory to read data from S3 and add to your pyspark classpath then set `kafka.ssl.engine.factory.class=your.code.S3Engine`

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion @OneCricketeer,
The issue has been resolved. This was apparently the regression bug which fixed now on Databricks side. My job is running fine now.

Comment: @HassanMehmood, The issue has been resolved. This was apparently the regression bug which fixed now on Databricks side. My job is running fine now.

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer documentating the fix, since as I understand your stacktrace, there's nothing related to Databricks in your error